# Including CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR doesn't work for subdirectory

Tags: cmake

The project has roughly the following structure:

```
include/
  lib_name/
    public_foo.h
    public_bar.h
src/
  CMakeLists.txt
  foo.c
  foo.h
  bar.c
  bar.h
CMakeLists.txt
```

The top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file defines a shared library target

```
add_library(lib_name SHARED "src/foo.c" "src/bar.c")
```

At the same time, there's a custom command

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/src/foo-impl.c" ...)
```

that generated `foo-impl.c` in the build directory that is included by `foo.c' like this:

```
#include <some_header.h>
#include <other.h>

#include "foo-impl.c"
```

In order to be able to include `foo-impl.c`I do the following in `src/CMakeLists.txt`

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

Looks like it should work, right?

Well, it doesn't work - the `src` directory is not added to compiler flags for `foo.c`. It seems like include directories affect only targets defined in the same directory (or subdirectories).

I know I can just do

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/src")
```

from the root `CMakeLists.txt` (in fact, this is how I'm doing it at the moment) but that's not acceptable: every subdirectory will see the parent's files and this can eventually lead to file name collisions.

How do people overcome this in large projects? or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most cmake commands, `include_directories` only affects targets in that directory and subdirectories. And IIRC only targets defined after the command. That's intentional. It's how you define different flags for different modules.

And when I say like most cmake commands, I really mean most. Most importantly including `add_definitions` and  `set` except with `CACHE` argument.

Also remember, that `include_directories` apples to **targets**, not files.

Either define the library in the subdirectory (makes most sense to me), put everything in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` or set the flags on the target only using `set_target_properties(lib_name PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-I${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src")` (must be done after the target is defined).